# Element event listener callback not working with custom event

Tags: javascript, custom-events

Element event listener callback not working with custom event, in the following code, document and window event listeners will be triggered, but not element's (tested on IE11, FF33, and Chrome38, results are the same.) Any idea? Did I misuse custom event?

```js
var el = document.getElementById('some-elem');
el.addEventListener('custom', function (e) {
  console.log("Element got event: " + e.type);
}, false, true);

document.addEventListener('custom', function (e) {
  console.log("document got event: " + e.type);
}, false);

window.addEventListener('custom', function (e) {
  console.log("window got event: " + e.type);
}, false);

var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
evt.initCustomEvent('custom', true, false);
document.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

```html
<div id="some-elem"></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the event never goes through the element, you're firing the event on `document`. Instead, fire it on the element:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('some-elem');
el.addEventListener('custom', function (e) {
  console.log("Element got event: " + e.type);
}, false, true);

document.addEventListener('custom', function (e) {
  console.log("document got event: " + e.type);
}, false);

window.addEventListener('custom', function (e) {
  console.log("window got event: " + e.type);
}, false);

var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
evt.initCustomEvent('custom', true, false);
el.dispatchEvent(evt); // <=== Change is here
```

```html
<div id="some-elem"></div>
```

---

Re your comment:

> the object dispatching the event is different from the listening object in my case, does it mean custom event can only be listened on the same object (except window and document)?

The event has to travel through the element, just like a `click` has to travel through the element for it to be seen by a `click` handler on the element. So for instance, if you had a `div` with the event handler on it, and there was an `img` *inside* the `div`, and you dispatched the event on the `img`, the handler on the `div` would trigger because the event bubbles to it (because you made the event bubble-able):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('some-elem');
el.addEventListener('custom', function (e) {
  snippet.log("Element got event: " + e.type);
}, false, true);

document.addEventListener('custom', function (e) {
  snippet.log("document got event: " + e.type);
}, false);

window.addEventListener('custom', function (e) {
  snippet.log("window got event: " + e.type);
}, false);

var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
evt.initCustomEvent('custom', true, false);
document.getElementById("some-span").dispatchEvent(evt); // <=== Change is here
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script><!-- snippet.js details: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<div id="some-elem">
  <span id="some-span"></span>
</div>
```

This diagram from [the DOM events spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) may help with picturing this stuff:

[image]

The element on which you call `dispatchEvent` is the "target" element (the dark blue `td` in that diagram).

Comment: the object dispatching the event is different from the listening object in my case, does it mean custom event can only be listened on the same object (except window and document)? Very confused. :(

Comment: @eihero: I've updated the answer to try to answer that comment.

Comment: Does it mean bubbling event will never go through the sibling elements?

Comment: @eihero: Correct. Events go from parent to child (capturing phase) and then from child to parent (bubbling phase). An event will never go to the target's siblings.

Comment: What If I want to `listen` and `dispatchEvent` on different files? I can't access the button element on one of those files. Still possible to use **CustomEvents**?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro - I'm afraid it's not clear to me what you're trying to do or how it relates to the answer above. By the time it's running, the concept of "files" is fairly moot in JavaScript browser-hosted code -- if the element is in the DOM, it's in the DOM.